# Kali Linux: Ошибка при установке cython

Tags: python, python-3.x, kali-linux

При

```
python3 -m pip install cython
```

Выдает

```
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
```

При

```
git clone https://github.com/oremanj/python-netfilterqueue
```

Выдает

```
fatal: destination path 'python-netfilterqueue' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

Comment: И в чем вопрос?

Comment: вопрос в том, как это решить

Comment: Ну очевидно же, следовать рекомендациям `pip`: не запускать его от рута, использовать виртуальное окружение.

Comment: Первое вообще-то предупреждение, что лучше `pip` рутом не запускать. А второе вам говорит, что такой каталог уже есть и в нём что-то лежит

Comment: Спасибо. Как тогда убрать рут, если CTRL+D и exit - не помогает?

Comment: @wunogradsky тогда необходимо разобраться с ОС, почему вся работа происходит из под root? Есть ли пользователи помимо root? Настроить сначала саму систему. Я надеюсь вы не на docker образе сидите

Comment: нет, на образе для виртуальной машины. сначала заходил как kali, потом поменял пароль у пользователя root и стал заходить под ним